# Ending a phone call with a voice command to help a person who is paralyzed

Tags: android, speech-recognition, telephony

I run a nonprofit organization that creates assistive technologies for people with disabilities.  I am working with a client who is quadriplegic - he is unable to use his limbs but can speak fine.  He currently controls just about everything on his Android phone using voice commands except for one critical function: there seems to be no way to END a call using a voice command.  Sure he can wait for the other person to hang up, but there are many circumstances where the need to end a call exists.  Of course the only method that my team knows of to end a call is to hit the end button or some other physical action, which of course he cannot do because he is paralyzed.

2 questions:

1) do any of the existing voice command apps have the capability to not only make calls but also end them with a voice command.  After an extensive search, sonalight appeared to be able to do it but failed upon testing.  Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

2) would it be possible to create an application that does the following:
- the app constantly runs in the background but waits for a trigger to begin speech recognition
- at the start of a call a speech recognition is started
- when a configurable key word or phrase is recognized the app ends the phone call

In theory it seems possible using the speech recognition and telephony APIs.

Lastly I want to thank the community here in advance for your help.  Your efforts have the opportunity to improve the quality of life for someone in need.  If anyone has more questions about this project or our organization in general, visit our website: [SpeakYourMindFoundation.org](http://speakyourmindfoundation.org).

Answer (score 1):

Couple options on how to end the call, assuming you can figure out the speech recognition trigger.

- Use reflection to get access to the hangup API in ITelephony
- Fake a Media key being pressed by an broadcast intent (pretend to be the hang up key from a bluetooth headset)

I can dig up some code later, I have tried both of these approaches and they work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks roostertech.  After doing a little more digging I have some concerns about newer versions of Android that prevent access to the ITelephony methods needed to pull off ending a phone call from another app.  Thoughts anyone?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I have a father who lost both arms and his sight after having Necrotizing Fasciitis. I'm having the same problem with an iPhone. So far, the best I've come up with is a capacitive stylus in his mouth or prosthetic arm, but the lack of sight and control of the stylus in the prosthetic or mouth make that different.